# Remove DocuSign Payment's Send without Payment ability

Tags: docusignapi

Using DocuSign REST API to create payment for Stripe.  Successful at creating the DocuSign envelope with the payment item.  When after signing is completed, DocuSign will prompt for payment.  There is a button to "Send without Payment" to skip the payment.  Is there a way to not allow for this?  Is there a way to disable the "Send without Payment"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I wonder if you have `required='true'` in the `formulaTab` you used for payment?
For me, that makes it required and no option to "send without payment" shows up.
Can you share your code if not so we can try it out?

Comment: Awesome.  That's it.  Thanks for pointing that out.  Making the formula tab require remove the "send without payment".

Comment: Would you mind marking this question as answered? thanks!